# How to filter grid view data from specific column of ng-repeat on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

JS File:

```
$scope.GridFilter = function ()
{
    var ddlCategory = $('#ddlValue').val();
    $scope.search = ddlCategory;
}
```

CHtml :

```
    <select id="ddlValue" name="ddlValue">
       <option value="">-- Select any Value--</option>
       <option ng-repeat="item in DataObject" value="{{item.Category}}">{{item.Category}}</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="GridFilter()">Filter Grid</button>
```

Grid:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in DataGrid | filter:search">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Category}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Status}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to filter data from drop-down value when button is clicked. 
It need to be searchable for Category column only, but it searching all other fields so the grid showing extra records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JQuery selector to get the selected value from dropdown. Add `ng-model` in select element for that. By this way, table will filter on drop-down selection without the need of a button:

```
<select name="Select" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="search">
    <option value="">-- Select any Value--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in DataObject" value="{{item.Category}}">{{item.Category}} 
    </option>
</select>
```

Check a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vbem54/17/)

If you want to use a button for the filtering action, use a new variable for the filtered array and set it in the filter function:

```
 $scope.GridFilter = function() {
     $scope.filteredGrid = $scope.DataGrid.filter((d) => d.Category == $scope.search);
 }
```

For example: [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vbem54/26/)